# Making battery pack for MMDVM

Tags: battery-charging

I have a MMDVM (multi mode digital voice modem) for dmr radio that runs on a Raspberry Pi.

I want to make my own power bank to run it when not in a vehicle, so I need to make a 5 V pack out of some 18650s.

Assuming I have 4 identical 18650 cells, can I run them as two pairs of 2 in parallel to:

1. ensure I have enough voltage for the buck.
2. extend the run time by doubling the mAh.

Can I connect these two sets of parallel cells as if they were 2 individual cells to a BMS board?

I've been looking and I can find a bunch that support 3 cells, but I haven't found one (easily at least) that supports 4 cells.

Since the batteries are the same mAh, age, and voltage, can they be combined to use 2 charging channels on the BMS, or does each cell require its own channel to the BMS?

Comment: Yes that should work. Cells in parallel function as one cell for balancing purposes. Make sure the charge level of the cells is within 0.1v when you connect them.